# Java form elements not showing up fully until activated i.e. clicked on

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, graphics, element

I've been trying to add Java form elements such as a textField and a passwordField to a fullscreen exclusive mode frame. The issue i've been having is that when I run the code, my form elements don't show up fully or not at all until I actually click on them.

Here's my code:

Master.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Master extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4927941474660261348L;
    static GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    static GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    static int WIDTH = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    static int HEIGHT = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    static Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    static Graphics2D g2d = null;
    static FontMetrics metrics = null;
    static URL vignetteURL = null;
    static Image vignette = null;
    static Rectangle red = new Rectangle(WIDTH - 35, 0, 35, 35);

    public Master() {
        super("Project Zenith");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setResizable(false);
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
        repaint();

        setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/hex.png")).getImage());
        vignetteURL = getClass().getResource("images/vignette2.png");

        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getX() >= red.getX() && e.getY() <= red.getHeight()) {
                    closeClicked();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

            }           
        });
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        vignette = toolkit.getImage(vignetteURL);
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Bebas Neue", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(168, 168, 168, 200));
        g2d.drawString("Project Zenith", 10, HEIGHT - 10);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0xFFA6A6));
        g2d.fill(red);
        g2d.drawImage(vignette, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, this); 

    }

    public void closeClicked() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Login extends Master {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Master l;
    static JTextField username;
    static JTextField password;
    static Graphics2D g2d = null;
    static FontMetrics metrics = null;
    static RoundRectangle2D loginRect = new RoundRectangle2D.Float((WIDTH / 2) - ((WIDTH / 4) / 2), (HEIGHT / 2) - ((HEIGHT / 4) / 2), (WIDTH / 4), (HEIGHT / 4), 20, 20);

    Login() {
        l = this;
        Font inputFont = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15);

        username = new JTextField();
        username.setBounds((WIDTH / 2) - (((int) loginRect.getY() - 10) / 2), (int) loginRect.getY() + 60, (int) loginRect.getY() - 10, 18);
        username.setFont(inputFont);
        username.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        username.setEditable(true);
        username.setBackground(new Color(0xE6E6E6));
        //username.setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().add(username);

        password = new JPasswordField();
        password.setBounds((WIDTH / 2) - (((int) loginRect.getY() - 10) / 2), (int) loginRect.getY() + 110, (int) loginRect.getY() - 10, 18);
        password.setFont(inputFont);
        password.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        password.setEditable(true);
        password.setBackground(new Color(0xE6E6E6));
        //password.setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().add(password);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds((WIDTH / 2) - 40, (int) loginRect.getY() + 155, 80, 20);
        loginButton.setFont(inputFont);
        loginButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        loginButton.setBackground(new Color(0xE6E6E6));
        //loginButton.setVisible(true);
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(username.getText());
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(loginButton);
        repaint();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fill(loginRect);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0xA8A8A8));
        g2d.drawString("Access Terminal", (Master.WIDTH / 2) - (metrics.stringWidth("Access Terminal") / 2), (int) loginRect.getY() + metrics.getHeight() + 2);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new Login();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't override `update` or `paint` of top level container.  Make sure you are maintaining the integrity of the paint chain by calling `super.paint`.  Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: There's no point calling `repaint` on a component which is not yet displayed on the screen

Comment: `static` is not your friend, it is NOT a means by which you enable cross object communication, it's a means by which your shoot yourself in the foot and wonder why you're limping...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, do you mind expanding a little bit? What would you recommend changing?

Comment: *"What would you recommend changing?"* - Everything.  `paint` paints over the top of every thing else, you should be using a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method to paint under the child components. Make use of an appropriate layout managers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for an explanation of how painting works in Swing.

The basic problem is:

1. You're breaking the painting chain
2. You're painting over child components

This is one (of many reasons) why you shouldn't override `paint` of top level containers.  Instead, start by using a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` (calling `super.paintComponent` before you perform any custom painting)

You should also make use of appropriate layout manager to better handle the differences in resolutions and font rendering requirements.

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

With a little clever planning, you can do some pretty advance things

[image]

Now, obviously this isn't in full screen, but that's kind of the point, you can now uncomment the line `gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);` and it will auto-magically realign itself, through the power of layout managers.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

                Login login = new Login();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project Zenith");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(login);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//              gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Master extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4927941474660261348L;

        private Rectangle closeRect;

        public Master() {

            addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getX() >= closeRect.getX() && e.getY() <= closeRect.getHeight()) {
                        closeClicked();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            closeRect = new Rectangle(getWidth() - 35, 0, 35, 35);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Bebas Neue", Font.PLAIN, 25));
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(new Color(168, 168, 168, 200));
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int y = (getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString("Project Zenith", 10, y);
            g2d.setColor(new Color(0xFFA6A6));
            g2d.fill(closeRect);
        }

        public void closeClicked() {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static class Login extends Master {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTextField username;
        private JTextField password;


        Login() {
            Font inputFont = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    RoundRectangle2D loginRect = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g2d.fill(loginRect);
                    g2d.setColor(new Color(0xA8A8A8));
                    g2d.draw(loginRect);
                }
            };
            content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 25, 0);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Access Terminal");
            label.setFont(new Font("Bebas Neue", Font.PLAIN, 25));
            label.setForeground(new Color(0xA8A8A8));

            content.add(label, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            username = new JTextField(25);
            username.setFont(inputFont);
            username.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            username.setEditable(true);
            username.setBackground(new Color(0xE6E6E6));
            //username.setVisible(true);
            content.add(username, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            password = new JPasswordField(25);
            password.setFont(inputFont);
            password.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            password.setEditable(true);
            password.setBackground(new Color(0xE6E6E6));
            //password.setVisible(true);
            content.add(password, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;

            JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
            loginButton.setFont(inputFont);
            loginButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            loginButton.setBackground(new Color(0xE6E6E6));
            loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(username.getText());
                }
            });
            content.add(loginButton, gbc);

            add(content);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, in your `Login` view, I've used compounding components to generate the "rounded border" effect, creating a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method to paint the effect.  This provides me with layout information from the child components in order to make determinations about how big the effect should be.  This is then added into a `Login` panel itself and through the use of layout managers, it all gets centered